# Problem with nested 'ifnum' when checking evenness of parameters

Tags: conditionals

I would like to know how to check properly for evenness or oddness within some macro. I have played a little with `fp` and `pgfmath` package, but it seems I am not keen enough in TeX to do it properly. Here is a sample example where I try to check evenness of 2 parameters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\IfEven#1{\pgfmathparse{int(mod(#1,2))}\ifnum\pgfmathresult=0}
\newcommand{\parity}[2]{%                                                                             
  \def\x{#1}%                                                                                         
  \def\y{#2}%                                                                                         
  \IfEven{\x}%                                                                                        
    \IfEven{\y}%                                                                                        
      {\x} and {\y} are even.%                                                                            
    \else%                                                                                              
      {\x} is even and {\y} is odd.%                                                                      
    \fi%                                                                                                
  \else%                                                                                              
    \IfEven{\y}%                                                                                        
      {\x} is odd and {\y} is even.%                                                                      
    \else%                                                                                              
      {\x} and {\y} are odd.%                                                                             
    \fi%                                                                                                
  %% If I put a second \fi here I got an error 'Extra \fi.', otherwise                                
  %% it compiles and works fine but there are two warnings:                                           
  %% (\end occurred when \ifnum on line 28 was incomplete)                                            
  %% (\end occurred when \ifnum on line 26 was incomplete)                                            
}

\begin{document}
\parity{0}{7}\\
\parity{3}{3}\\
\parity{2}{6}\\
\parity{1}{4}\\
\end{document}
```

I do understand that I should write a second `\fi` (but it does not compile). Otherwise, it compiles, displays what I was expecting, but I do not feel comfortable at all with the warnings... and I guess the more I will be using this macro, the more I will have warnings.

So If you have any suggestions...

Comment: TeX comes with a conditional for testing oddness `\ifodd`, so I think it would be simpler to use that. `\ifodd\y odd code\else even code\fi`.

Comment: I followed your suggestion. If I remove the {} around the tests and add the second \fi, it works fine. Thanks ! However I can't help thinking that I have not understood why the previous approach does not work.

Comment: It's probably something to do with the `\ifnum` being hidden in the code that isn't executed. I think the problem is similar to that in [Do all \if's need to be defined before a nested if?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315749/do-all-ifs-need-to-be-defined-before-a-nested-if)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When conditional text is skipped over, TeX still keeps track of `\if...`, `\else` and `\fi`.

When you call `\parity{1}{0}`, the first `\IfEven` is expanded, leaving `\ifnum` in the input stream. Since the conditional returns false, the inner `\IfEven` is not expanded and the first `\else` is matched to `\ifnum`.

There is an old trick for this, using `\if`. The trick is ascribed to the Grand Wizard himself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\IsEven#1{%
  TT\fi
  \pgfmathparse{int(mod(#1,2))}%
  \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0
}
\newcommand{\parity}[2]{%
  \if\IsEven{#1}%
    \if\IsEven{#2}%
      #1 and #2 are even.%
    \else%
      #1 is even and #2 is odd.%
    \fi
  \else
    \if\IsEven{#2}%
      #1 is odd and #2 is even.%
    \else
      #1 and #2 are odd.%
    \fi
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\parity{0}{7}

\parity{3}{3}

\parity{2}{6}

\parity{1}{4}

\end{document}
```

This way there is always a conditional to make the correct balance. When it is in non-skipped over text, `\if` triggers expansion of `\IsEven` which will leave

```
\if TT\fi
<code>
\ifnum...
```

and the conditionals will be balanced again. The `\if TT\fi` part expands to nothing.

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify the `\if TT\fi`trick : you need two tokens and arbitrarily chose "T" ?

Comment: @ChristophFrings Yes, it's immaterial what you choose; they just need to be two unexpandable tokens.

Answer (score 3):

don't do

```
\def\IfEven#1{\pgfmathparse{int(mod(#1,2))}\ifnum\pgfmathresult=0}
```

as such a syntax leaves trailing `\else` and `\fi` not matched by a tex-primitive `\if`.

Either use `\if` syntax or use argument syntax

```
\pgfmathparse{int(mod(#1,2))}%
\ifnum\pgfmathresult=0
yes
\else
no
\fi
```

or

```
\def\IfEven#1#2#3{\pgfmathparse{int(mod(#1,2))}\ifnum\pgfmathresult=0 %need this space!
 #2%
 \else
 #3%
 \fi}
```

then

```
\IfEven{\x}{yes}{no}
```