# LuaLaTeX and polyglossia 1.47

Tags: luatex, polyglossia, hebrew

When I use Hebrew with `polyglossia` 1.47 and LuaLaTeX on TeXLive 2019, I get an error message that I don't get with `polyglossia` 1.46. Here is my MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{SBL Hebrew}[Script=Hebrew]
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\begin{document}
Text in English and \texthebrew{עברית}. Text...
\end{document}
```

The messages I get

```
Package polyglossia Warning: Hebrew is not supported with LuaTeX.
(polyglossia)                I will proceed with the compilation, but
(polyglossia)                the output is not guaranteed to be correct
(polyglossia)                and may look very wrong. on input line 6.



(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luabidi/luabidi.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luabidi/luabidi-footnotes.def)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/hebrewcal.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/cal-util.def))
Setting \if@calendar@hebrew
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/babel-hebrewalph.def)

! Too many }'s.
l.120   \fi}
          %
! Extra \fi.
l.121 \fi
```

Comment: Make a bug report. You can also try babel's new bidi/hebrew support. Polyglossia seems not to support hebrew with lualatex anyway.

Comment: This looks like a bug in `gloss-hebrew.ldf` (`\if...`..`\if`-matching). Report it at https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues

Comment: the code uses an \if that is not defined. A work around is `\makeatletter\newif\if@nonlatin\makeatother` before loading the language.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion (I reported it as a possible bug) and for the workaround.

Comment: I wonder, though, why this `\if` is accessed at all with lualatex, as the definition is in `\ifxetex`

Comment: https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/389

Comment: Never mind, I [see why](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315749/)

Comment: BTW @UlrikeFischer I think the warning that polyglossia does not support Hebrew is wrong. But we need confirmation from a Hebrew user.