# Weird error: "\csname if@chapter@pp\endcsname" inside of \if ~ \fi

Tags: conditionals, ifthenelse

I can't understand why the following doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newif\iftemp \tempfalse

\iftemp
    \csname if@chapter@pp\endcsname 
        \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendices} 
    \fi
\fi

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

while the following works:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\def\temptemp{temp}

\ifthenelse{\equal{\temptemp}{wrong}}{
    \csname if@chapter@pp\endcsname 
        \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendices} 
    \fi
}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Seems like `\iftemp ... \fi` does NOT ignore it's content even when \iftemp is false.

For a separate reason, I want to use `\iftemp` instead of `\ifthenelse{...}`.
Any hotfix here?

Comment: To keep `\if(true|false) ... \fi` paired, try the trick `\expandafter\ifx\csname if@chapter@pp\expandafter\endcsname\csname iftrue\endcsname` from [Heiko Oberdiek's previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315752)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conditional `\if@chapter@pp` needs to be defined for the code to do something sensible. Based on the name, I guess you're loading `appendix`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{appendix}

\newif\iftemp
%\tempfalse % a new conditional always starts false

\expandafter\iftemp
    \csname if@chapter@pp\endcsname
        \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendices}
    \fi
\fi

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What is the problem? When `\iftemp` returns false, the “true branch” is skipped, but *explicit* conditionals are taken into account. But `\csname if...\endcsname` is skipped over as no expansion is performed, so it it doesn't count as an explicit conditional.

With `\expandafter`, the token `\if@chapter@pp` is formed before `\iftemp` is examined.

More simply, use `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`:

```
\makeatletter
\iftemp
    \if@chapter@pp
        \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendices}
    \fi
\fi
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks! That part is in the .sty file, so I just change it to `\if@chapter@pp`. Now it works perfect! (Instead of loading the appendix package, I just define `\newif\if@chapter@pp \@chapter@pptrue`)

Answer (score 4):

In the first conditional

```
\iftemp
  \csname if@chapter@pp\endcsname 
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendices} 
  \fi
\fi
```

`\iftemp` finds the *first* `\fi` since there is no other *explicit* `\if<...>`. And since `\tempfalse`, there is an extra (unpaired) `\fi`, hence the error

```
! Extra `\fi`.
```

---

In the second conditional

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\temptemp}{wrong}}{%
  \csname if@chapter@pp\endcsname 
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendices} 
  \fi
}{}
```

you should understand that `\ifthenelse` is defined to only take a single argument - the condition. After evaluating the condition, it either executes `\@firstoftwo` or `\@secondoftwo`. Under `\ifthenelse` there is no closing `\fi` required.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way I can use \if ... \fi instead?